# Java CookiePolicy ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER denying cookies

Tags: java, http, cookies, dns, hostname

I'm trying to figure out when a specific cookie gets set, and update something based on its new value. I'm trying to do this by implementing my own cookie policy

my problems deals within the HttpCookie.domainMatches method.

When I use the CookiPolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER policy, it rejects several cookies.

The cookies have a domain of "HostName" (ie. machineName123). This is clearly an invalid domain.

Should I set the domain explictly on the server side?

If I get the CanonicalHostName using InetAddress, I just get an IP Address...

for example:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, new CookiePolicy() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldAccept(java.net.URI uri, final java.net.HttpCookie cookie) {
            if(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER.shouldAccept(uri, cookie)) {
                   //custom code here
                }
                System.out.println("Accepting cookie uri Host: " + uri.getHost() + " name:" + cookie.getName() + " value: " + cookie.getValue() + " domain: " + cookie.getDomain() + " path: " + cookie.getPath() );
                System.out.println("Domain matches uri: " + HttpCookie.domainMatches(cookie.getDomain(), uri.getHost()));
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("Rejecting cookie  uri Host: " +  uri.getHost() + " name:" + cookie.getName() + " value: " + cookie.getValue() + " domain: " + cookie.getDomain() + " path: " + cookie.getPath() );
            System.out.println("Domain matches uri: " + HttpCookie.domainMatches(cookie.getDomain(), uri.getHost()));
            return false;
        };
    }));
```

Is there another way to determine when a specific cookie gets set? (it could happen from several connections), or is there another way resolve hostnames?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cookie policy to accept all cookies you need to use the predefined cookie policy:

```
CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL
```

Example:

```
CookieManager myCustomCookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

OR

```
myCustomCookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not all cookies should be accepted. I ended up using ORIGINAL_SERVER policy and using a few special rules to identify machine names that aren't "correct" domains